# How can I use strip_tags in regular Ruby code (non-rails)?

Tags: html, ruby, tags, strip, actionview

I need to turn HTML into plain text. There's a nice function that does that in ActionView's SanitizeHelper, but I have trouble understanding how I can reference it and use it in a simple test.rb file.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

I would like to be able to call `strip_tags("<b>lol</b>") => "lol"`

Answer (score 33):

The question is quite old, but I had the same problem recently. I found a simple solution: gem [sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize). It's light, works fine and has additional options if you need them.

```
Sanitize.clean("<b>lol</b>") #=> "lol"
```

Answer (score 25):

ActiveSupport is the only Rails framework that supports cherry-picking individual components. The other frameworks, including ActionView, must be required en-masse:

```
require 'action_view'
```

Note that this require won't necessarily load all of ActionView. Barring situations where thread-safety requires that autoloads happen eagerly, it merely sets up autoloads and requires common dependencies. That means that following the require, if you reference, e.g. `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper`, it will cause `action_view/helpers /sanitize_helper.rb` to be required.

Therefore the correct, supported way to accomplish what you desire using ActionView is the following:

```
require 'action_view'

class Test < Test::Unit::TestCase # or whatever
  include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

  def my_test
    assert_equal "lol", strip_tags("<b>lol</b>")
  end
end
```

This isn't well-documented; I based this answer primarily off of [the discussion on this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3943).

Comment: Do you need to explicitly require action_view? in which Rails version? I don't recall having needed at least for Rails 2.3.x

Comment: The question is about using strip_tags _outside_ of Rails, so, yes, you do need to include it.

Comment: oh, I see, indeed the OP does not say he's using Rails.

Answer (score 18):

I believe this should be enough:

```
"<b>lol</b>".gsub(/<[^>]*>/ui,'') #=> lol
```

You can use Nokogiri as well:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<b>lol</b>")
doc.text #=> "lol"
```

You still can go with the Rails one by doing something like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'action_view'

class Foo
  include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

  def test
    strip_tags("<b>lol</b>")
  end
end

f = Foo.new
puts f.test #=> lol
```

Comment: You never know what browsers will do if you just put an opening pointing bracket without ever closing it; I definitely wouldn't assume that the `gsub` solution is safe unless you put an extra `.gsub(/[<>]/, '')` at the end.  (And even then I won't vouch for it.)

Comment: +1 for the Nokogiri comment. That works perfectly for my needs.

Comment: Worth a note, nokogiri is a HUGE library  that usually compiles from source...might be a little overkill to use the entire parsing library for just this, when Rails is shipping with plenty of tricks inside the box.

Comment: Do not write you own sanitizers. They will always fail in some corner-cases and hilarity (i.e. hacking) ensues! Use proper libraries.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't use it very often, then you can use:

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(your_html_string)
```

else you can define a method in test_helper.rb file like:

```
def strip_html_tags(string)
    ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(string)
end
```

And then in your test.rb file, use this like:

```
strip_html_tags(your_html_string)
```

Answer (score 8):

The question is quite old, but you can call it in your `test.rb` like this:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags("<b>lol</b>") => "lol"
```

Answer (score 1):

With this example:

```
"&lt;p&gt;<i>example</i>&lt;/p&gt;"
```

This helped me:

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(Nokogiri::HTML(example).text)
```

Output:

```
example
```

Comment: Combinig this two options finally worked for me correctly!

Comment: @ManoloPirolo Good!)

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you would require and include `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper` but there are several dependencies that don't get included when you do that. You can require them yourself to be able to use `strip_tags`.

```
require 'erb'
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors'
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/encoding'
require 'action_view/helpers/capture_helper'
require 'action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper'

include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

strip_tags("<b>lol</b>") # => "lol"
```

This is assuming you have rails 3 gems installed.

Comment: ActionView doesn't support cherry-picking requires -- that's why this approach ends up being so gross. See my answer for further details.

Answer (score -1):

```
HTML::FullSanitizer.new.sanitize('<b>lol</b>') # => "lol"
```