# how to use strip_tags and truncate inside my Model.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

strip_tags works for me in my view page, but not in my model (i'm using it in a before_save function)

Comment: Don't strip_tags. Just encode HTML entities on output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all html tags from attributes in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576394/remove-all-html-tags-from-attributes-in-rails)

Comment: duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576394/remove-all-html-tags-from-attributes-in-rails, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354060/how-can-i-use-strip-tags-in-regular-ruby-code-non-rails

Comment: @meagar What if I want to search a field which contains HTML, but only the text content?

Comment: @meagar There are a bunch of situations where you actually want to strip_tags rather than escape entities. For example, your models to_param method might create a vanity URL from an attribute which is allowed to contain markup.

Answer (score -11, accepted):

`strip_tags` is a helper method and helpers aren't available inside models as a rule.

You might want to look at using something like the [sanitize gem](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) instead

Comment: From the pure orthodoxy that's true, but isn't a shame that you have a library there that just does the task but you _can't_ use it? see the duplicated questions linked in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 75):

You can also access helpers in your models like this:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(text)
```

Comment: The only *actually correct* answer to OPs *actual question*, languishing at the bottom.

Comment: This is the only correct answer that answers the actual question. I agree

Comment: Glad you are a rebel Mr @Aleks. Thanks.

Comment: strip_tags is just a helper around `Loofah.fragment(html_frag).text` which can be directly used in models

Comment: @Zeragamba yes but unless you already added Loofah to your Gemfile, it's not safe to use it, rails can change the implementation of the method anytime and remove the dependency and your code will break.

Answer (score 16):

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(your_html_string)
```

This will work for you.
Or you can define a helper like:

```
def strip_html_tags(string)
    ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(string)
end
```

And then use this like:

```
strip_html_tags(your_html_string)
```

To remove some specific tags pass additional parameters.
Source: [Sanitize Rails API Dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize)

Answer (score 0):

So, I didn't like any of these solutions as i'd rather keep view functionality out of my models. So instead I used a decorator (like https://github.com/drapergem/draper) and was then able to use the helper method short cut `h.strip_tags`.

Answer (score -3):

The poor man's truncator:

```
my_string[0, 145]
```

It will work in a model without having to call helper methods from ActionController::Base. It won't add the elipsis for you, but that's probably easy to fix...